# Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I'm running selenium and when a ask to open Chrome it open and after 1 sec closes

From my understanding that happens becasue chromedrive is not updated to my google version 123.0.6312.87 (oficial) (arm64) form MacOs Sonoma. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, review your question because it lacks of clarity. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask